# extracted data file containing range function is not active

Tags: perl

i have extracted the following data in a file

```
0..5 
8..10 
12..16
```

but these are not working as range function. i have stored these in an array.

```
@arr=('0..5,8..10,12..16');
```

after printing the array it gives

```
0..5 
8..10 
12..16
```

but i need output as

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
8 9 10
12 13 14 15 16
```

am not getting where is the problem. why the stored data (..) is not working as range. function

Answer (score 2):

You're starting with string representations of ranges, not actual perl ranges.

To get a perl array, you must convert your data.  You could use `eval` like others have recommended.  However, that's like using a machete to perform a haircut.

Instead, I'd advise using more precision tools to extract the range boundaries from the string and then build your new data structure.  Using `split` or a regex could easily pull the values.  The following does so using the latter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($start, $end) = /(\d+)/g;
    my @array = ($start .. $end);
    print "@array\n";
}

__DATA__
0..5
8..10
12..16
```

Outputs:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
8 9 10
12 13 14 15 16
```

#### Addendum for multiple entries on a row

The following allows for multiple ranges to be on a single row.  Note, I'm using `split` in this version for the sake of variety, although I could have easily used a regex as well:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @array;
    for my $range (split ' ') {
        my ($start, $end) = split /\.{2}/, $range, 2;
        push @array, ($start .. $end);
    }
    print "@array\n";
}

__DATA__
0..5
4..9 14..18
8..10
12..16
```

Outputs:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
4 5 6 7 8 9 14 15 16 17 18
8 9 10
12 13 14 15 16
```

Comment: i have another data set 4..9 14..18 now i want to find the numbers of these data set that lie in above data. output should be 4,5,8,9,14,15,16 and the total count=7. how should i compare these two range of data set using same approach as above. @miller

Comment: I've added a secondary solution that shows one method for allowing for multiple entries on a row.

Answer (score 1):

Data is data. Perl does not evaluate data as Perl (i.e. expand `..` range operator) unless you explicitly tell it to with `eval`.  The following debug session should clarify things for you.

```
$ perl -de0

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   0
  DB<1> @arr = ('0..5,8..10,12..16')

  DB<2> p @arr
0..5,8..10,12..16
  DB<3> eval "@arr = ('0..5,8..10,12..16')"

  DB<4> p @arr
0..5,8..10,12..16
  DB<5> @arr = ('0..5','8..10','12..16')

  DB<6> p @arr
0..58..1012..16

  DB<7> @arr = eval "(0..5,8..10,12..16);"

  DB<8> x @arr
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  8
7  9
8  10
9  12
10  13
11  14
12  15
13  16
  DB<9>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Perl to expand string ranges into Perl ranges, you must [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) that data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

my @arr=('0..5','8..10','12..16');
foreach my $range (@arr) {
   say join ' ', eval ($range);
}

__END__
0 1 2 3 4 5
8 9 10
12 13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this to store the values in the array:

```
@arr=((0..5),(8..10),(12..16));
```